# Using RGB_565 for background image in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am currently working on a game with Andengine, GLES1 and have found on one of my devices it runs really slow, (around 15 FPS). To improve this as well as using a SpriteGroup I have converted the background images to RGB_565. So, for example,

```
mBitmapTextureAtlasBackground = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 
    512,BitmapTextureFormat.RGB_565,TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
mBgRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
    .createFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlasBackground, mActivity, 
    "backgroundgame1.png", 0, 0);
BackgroundSprite = new Sprite(0.0f, 0.0f, mCamera.getWidth(),mCamera.getHeight(), mBgRegion);
```

However the images are as follows, the one on the right is wtih RGB_565,

[image: Original Image]
[image: RGB_565]

(The black rectangle on the first image is an advert I blocked out!).
Is there something I have omitted? I would be greatful for any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, it appears this is down to my own ignorance as regards image formats :$

I have left the question however just in case someone was wandering similar. I was using texture packer which gave me an option for texture format, (png) and at the same time an image format, (RGB565), so I assumed that RGB565 was a reduced version of png without alpha. While looking into my problem I came across this,

[How to convert 32 bit PNG to RGB565?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118374/how-to-convert-32-bit-png-to-rgb565)

And this,

[Why there is .pvr file in OpenGL(IOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590819/why-there-is-pvr-file-in-openglios)

I understand now that png and RGB565 are indeed very different!